If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k =0$

Problem. Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k =0$.

The problem arises from the following question:

Let $(e_i)_{i=1}^\infty $ be an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert spcae $H$. Prove that $u_n= \frac 1 {\sqrt n} \sum_{k=1}^n e_k$ weakly converges to $0$.

I am aware of a proof using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, using the fact that $\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{a_k}{\sqrt{n-(m+1)}} \le \sqrt{\sum_{k=m+1}^n a_k^2}$. However, I am looking for different approaches for this problem, perhaps more "elementary".

What would be more elementary than Cauchy-Schwarz?

Seiberg-Witten-Floer cohomology, perhaps?
More seriously - sure, CS is elementary enough. But as this is a simply formulated question in "calc 2", I do expect there to be a solution that does not use linear algebra.

Does this answer your question? compute norm and weak limit in Hilbert space of $u^N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k=1}^N e_k$

@Robert Why would you expect that? You are trying to answer a question about a orthonormal basis. This has Cauchy-Schwarz written all over it (well, in captial letters, but I don't feel like screaming). Also, I do not really see how Cauchy-Schwarz is linear algebra and not analysis.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029450/let-a-n-be-a-positive-sequence-and-sum-n-1-infty-a-n2-a-calculate?noredirect=1

If you really want to avoid Cauchy-Schwarz, then you can proceed as follows: for each $R$, $\lvert a_k\rvert=\lvert \sqrt{R}a_k R^{-1/2}\rvert\leqslant R a_k^2+1/R$ hence
$$
\left\lvert \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right\rvert
\leqslant \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} \left\lvert a_k\right\rvert
+\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=n_0+1}^n a_k^2 R+\frac{\sqrt{n}}R.
$$
For a fixed $\delta$, choose $R=\sqrt{n}/\delta$, so that the previous inequality becomes
$$
\left\lvert \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right\rvert
\leqslant \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} \left\lvert a_k\right\rvert
+\frac 1{\delta}\sum_{k=n_0+1}^n a_k^2  +\delta
$$
hence for each $n_0$ and $\delta$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right\rvert
\leqslant  \frac 1{\delta}\sum_{k=n_0+1}^\infty a_k^2  +\delta.
$$
Since $n_0$ is arbitrary, we get for each $\delta$ that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right\rvert
\leqslant  \delta.
$$

Nice proof. Quick question: why do you have a factor of 2 in your inequality $\lvert a_k\rvert=\lvert \sqrt{R}a_k R^{-1/2}\rvert\leqslant 2R a_k^2+2/R$? It is obviously true, but by directly applying AM-GM we get a factor of $1/2$ instead, so was wondering where it came from?

Actually it should not be there since $|ab|\leq 2|ab|\leq a^2+b^2$.

@DavideGiraudo This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
